# Dynamic data for dropdown in Azure b2C signup policy?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am working on a project where i have to use a signup/sign-in policy to create a custom html page which is working fine. Now the requirement is We need to fill the form dropdown field with some dynamic data from our database.

Since we can't use iframes or javascript with azure b2c..is there a way to manipulate input tag thats rendered in

```
<div id="api"></div>
```

if not is there any other strategy to populate dynamic data into these custom attributes without typing them in manually into azure policy? perhaps any powershell command? or Azure API such as graph api?

Comment: Well to have our own registration page  I opt to use Azure Graph API to insert data programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this links helps you:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-customize-ui-custom

The important part is the third note:
*For security reasons, the use of JavaScript is currently blocked for customization. To unblock JavaScript, use of a custom domain name for your Azure AD B2C tenant is needed.*

BR